# JSF 1.2 managed bean how to get the getter value

Tags: jsf

I new to Java and JSf, am getting null pointer error when accessing a getter value from backing bean in controller.
Here is the code snippet :

JSP;
input text area and am able see the sysout in setter the value submitted from page and not able to access the getter values.
faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>researchHisttoryController</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.controller.ResearchHisttoryController</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>history</property-name>
            <property-class>com.researchhistory.model.ShipmentHistory</property-class>
            <value>#{history}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
Controller class:

private ShipmentHistory history;

//getters and setter followed;
```

am accessing varaible from ShipmentHistory class 
as 
 `getHistory.getTrackNumber; NPE error`

```
ShipmentHistory.java
private String trackNumber;
//getters and setters
```

can please help me out where am doing wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you give your jsf page code and backing bean code that how to set a value from input text

Comment: <h:inputTextarea id="trackingNumber"
   binding="#{researchBackingBean.trackingNumber}"
   validator="#{researchBackingBean.processesValidate}"
   value="#{shipmentHistory.trackingNumbers}" />

Comment: BackingBean validation:  private HtmlInputTextarea trackingNumber; let me know if this good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then `#{history}` is just `null`. Apparently you haven't declared it as a managed bean.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>history</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.researchhistory.model.ShipmentHistory</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

But this is kind of odd. A model should not be treated as a controller. Depending on the functional requirement, there must surely be better ways. Perhaps you just want a new blank instance of `ShipmentHistory` everytime when the `ResearchHisttoryController` get created. In that case, do the job in the (post)constructor of the backing bean instead.

```
public ResearchHisttoryController() {
    history = new History();
}
```

*(please note that you've a typo in the backing bean class name)*